Select multiple vertices around an edge in one click (Blender 4.2)
I am trying to select all vertices around a single edge of a circular object.
I am watching an old blender 4.0 tutorial which mentions Alt + Click to select all around but that isn't working for me. I can hold shift and select multiple but this is meaning I have to press every one individually. I have also discovered the circle selection which allows me to select them by "painting" over the ones I want.
I am using Blender 4.2 on a mac in case that is relevant. Can anyone help me?

4.0 is not that old, that Alt+ click to select loops existed before and still exists. However, just like the Loop Cut tool, it can only select loops where it can detect them. So I'm pretty sure it is not a matter of 4.2 and the Mac (at least I'm not aware if this feature doesn't exist on Mac, but it definitely still does on Windows in the latest version), but rather of your geometry. We could answer the question more easily if you would show the mesh and which loop you tried to select with this method.

There are conditions for alt+click to work:

You cannot be using the "emulate 3 mouse button" option (edit, preferences, input)

If you need to use that option because your mouse doesn't have the wheel to press, then you can select loops with double click (unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for faces, but works for edges)


Your topology must be good!! (That means your mesh must contain 4-sided faces, and only 4-sided faces)

Faces with a different number of vertices will not form a loop (even if those vertices aren't connected to anything)
Edges that go to an n-pole (vertex with more than 4 edged) don't form a loop, although n-poles are not a topology issye


The edges/faces must be connected (vertex duplications or disconnected faces interrupt the loop)

